# GWT SuggestBoxPopUp Z-index

Tags: gwt, z-index, suggestbox

I am currently working with GWT and the SuggestBox. 
The Suggestboxpopup is appearing behind the panel the Suggestbox is placed on. I am aware that there is an issue with the Suggestbox popup's z-index but I am looking to see if anyone has another solution other than hard-wiring the the z-index in the CSS.

The reason for this is the panel the suggest box is on has a Z-index helper which moves the panel to the front anytime it is clicked. While a super high z-index will resolve the issue i am wondering has anyone found a better solution which will allow the popup to move with the other widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is an [known problem](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1351) in SuggestBox which is in the issues list of GWT. It has been closed recently because of a lack of activity in the issue, you can put a comment to reopen it though.

I think it is not very important because no much apps need a suggest box on a popup.

I had the same issue in a project and I solved it with css as you suggest.